# Android missing android.net.StaticIpConfiguration. Can't set new instance or import

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors, static-ip-address

I am trying to set a static IP in android. Here is the code

```
Object ipAssignment = getEnumValue("android.net.IpConfiguration$IpAssignment", "STATIC");
callMethod(config, "setIpAssignment", new String[] { "android.net.IpConfiguration$IpAssignment" }, new Object[] { ipAssignment });
Object staticIpConfig = newInstance("android.net.StaticIpConfiguration");
```

I am getting an error in the 3rd line. "newinstance() cannot be applied to android.net.StaticIpConfiguration." Also noticed that I can't import android.net.StaticIpConfiguration.

I tried looking online but couldn't find much about the class. Was it removed? How do I import it? My build target is 25 and min version 15

Comment: Looking at this [reference doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/package-summary.html) I see no reference to `IpConfiguration`, unless that is an internal function that does not have a public API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Was it removed?

It was never part of the Android SDK, AFAIK.

> How do I import it?

You don't. That class is part of Android, but it is not part of the SDK, and so it cannot be imported directly. It also may not exist in all versions of Android, may be changed in various versions of Android, may be changed in various firmware builds (e.g., custom ROMs, different device manufacturers, etc.).

Comment: Is there a way to import it indirectly so I can get the code to work?

Comment: @PythonLord: There is no concept in Java of "import it indirectly". It looks like your code snippet is using some framework that employs Java reflection, and reflection is the typical approach for doing the sorts of things that you are trying (and probably shouldn't be trying). You might look at the documentation for that framework and see what parameters this `newInstance()` static-imported method needs.